# Why is this combination of a covariant derivative and vector field a (1,1)-tensor?

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors

I have a question regarding something Penrose says in section 14.3 of The Road to Reality.

It says '...when $\nabla$ acts on a vector field $\xi$, the resulting quantity $\nabla \xi$ is a $(1,1)$-valent tensor.'

I understand that $\nabla$ is a $(0,1)$-tensor and $\xi$ as a vector field is a $(1,0)$-tensor, so it sort of makes sense that $\nabla \xi$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor.  However, what's throwing me off is the wording "acts on".  I understand that the idea of $\nabla$ is that it gives a notion of derivative not just for scalar fields, but vector fields and general tensors.  It seems "acts on" implies that $\nabla \xi$ should be a $0$-tensor.

So my question is: is this just a poor choice of language, and is $\nabla \xi$ just $\nabla$ with respect to a vector field (instead of just a single vector) $\xi$, or is the actual evaluation of $\xi$ by $\nabla$ not a scalar field as I would expect, but actually a $(1,1)$-tensor?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have received an answer to my question (see comment below), but now I'd really like more detail behind how, if I may ask in this same question, the $(1,1)$-tensor $\nabla \xi$ describes how $\xi$ changes from point to point (intuitively and concretely, preferably, but at least intuitively).

Comment: $\nabla$ makes a $(p,q)$-tensor one of rank $(p,q+1)$

Comment: @ShuchangZhang Alright, but if $\nabla \xi$ is a $(1,1)$-tensor, how does it describe, intuitively, the change of $\xi$ as we move from point to point?

Comment: It describes the change of tangent vector $\xi$ along the curve on the manifold. You could see covariant derivative for detailed information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A $(1,1)$-tensor can be thought of as a linear map that sends vectors to vectors; so given a vector $X$ based at $p$, $\nabla\xi(X)=\nabla_X \xi$ will be another vector based at $p$, which you should think of as the change in the vector field $\xi$ when you move a small amount in the direction $X$ starting from $p$.

Comment: That helps a little.  But what aspect of the vector field, exactly, is changing?

Comment: @AlexPetzke: The difference between two vectors is a vector, so the rate of change of a vector is a vector. In the case of flat space this can be made quite literal - all the vectors in the vector field can be considered as elements of the same space and thus compared and differentiated - this is the directional derivative applied to the Cartesian components of the vectors. In arbitrary manifolds things aren't really as simple, and you need to introduce some new machinery to get a similar notion of directional derivative, which is exactly what the covariant derivative is.

Comment: I hadn't compared to the Euclidean case, which I'm familiar with.  That does make more sense now, thanks.